# Seeking JS framework/library similar to AWS CloudFormation designer

Tags: library, javascript

I'm looking for a JS framework/library to create a designer similar to how the AWS CloudFormation designer works.

The library should preferable be able to auto layout components given a definition, similar to how the CF designer can generate and show the layout if you paste a template into it.

What language the definition files must be in does not matter a whole lot but it's better if it's some sort of JSON or XML or YAML.

Comment: I cannot figure out what sequence of keywords would lead google to give me the answer I want.

Comment: Did you find any?

Comment: @XaviMontero Unfortunately, no, and I stopped looking after a while. But I think it can be implemented using a layout algorithm like "elkjs" (github.com/kieler/elkjs).

Comment: There are a couple of open-sourced webapps like n8n and NocoDb that do some nice graphs for automation... maybe should we explore what are they using. n8n sample graphs: https://blog.elest.io/content/images/2023/02/workflow2.png + https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/86527202/262362026-c3775d27-f75d-4263-8903-dd66427de4b4.png